# isPopupMenu method in openJDK 8

Tags: swing, java

Just came across openJDK [`JPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html) class method [`isPopupMenu()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.java#l880), which is implemented as follows:

```
   private boolean isPopupMenu() {
        return  ((invoker != null) && !(invoker instanceof JMenu));
    }
```

I was wondering if that is best way to determine if that is a popup menu or not?

Comment: Since it's a private method, it's not _any_ way, best or otherwise, that you can use for yourself.

Comment: So is the question "*Can I use the same logic for the same purpose?*" (since `getInvoker()` is public it seems implementable?). I suppose it's not a really good way to rely on internal logic, but at least now the question makes sense to me (removed my previous noisy comments, sorry)

Comment: The given logic is perhaps "the best" as far as openJDK's implementation of `JPopupMenu` is concerned.  As an example for an application programmer to follow, it might be unnecessarily general.

Answer (score 0):

For the current OpenJDK, sure, it should work. If future OpenJDK versions introduce different menu types or redesign the implementation (which seems unlikely, not sure how much interest there is in Swing these days), your method might start giving incorrect results.

Maybe there is a more direct way of achieving what you need? Or if you are writing a UI component, giving the responsibility for making the distinction to the calling code?